# S function for 2 D look up Table, Similar to "sfix_look1_dyn.mex32"

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

I need some information about "sfix_look1_dyn.mex32" file. Currently I am using this mex file, with the help of masked s function block. I am using this block only for 1 D look up related calculations. But if I want to use similar kind of logic for 2 D Look up table then is it possible to use same mex file ? Basically I want to know is there any way out so that, for 2 D lookup I can give values of Table Data as Inputs.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't use same mex file or tlc for 2-D lookup, its for Dynamic lookup 1D Block

However, you can use *[n-D Lookup Table](http://www.mathworks.in/help/simulink/slref/ndlookuptable.html)* block

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. My problem is I want n-D look up table to which I can input the Values which we assign in Table Data, Breakpoints etc. I want to give those parameter as inputs. Here that is not possible. The Main reason behind doing this is, I want to use N- D lookup Table for enumerated parameters. If I use those Parameters inside N-D look up Table, It gives an error as it requires numeric type Data. If I get something like "sfix_look1_dyn.mex32" then can convert enumerated parameters to integer and then can pass to Look up table.  "sfix_look1_dyn.mex32" does it for 1 D Lookup.

Comment: @Swapnil, you can always mask n-d lookup block inside a Atomic Subsytem see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24680462/1870232) answer, you may also have to play around with Simulink API inside Parameter Dialog callback if that's sounds too complex, I'd suggest writing your own s-function to perform desired operation, but that's the last thing you have to do.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But here the problem is when I use masked subsystem and its callbacks to convert my enumerated parameters, I loose the tunability of parameters that may cause a problem after code generation.