# Simulink Mask Parameters

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to create a subsystem that has a transfer function in it. Everything except one coefficient in the denominator is set in this transfer function.

How can I promote only this parameter, instead of promoting the entire denominator of the transfer function into the the subsystem's mask? When the user double clicks on the sub system, I want to make it so the mask only requests this single parameter, rather than the whole denominator. Is this possible?

It's a third order system: `[1 (parameter) 9 1]`.

I want to set the (parameter) coefficient in the mask.

Comment: How does your denominator look like, I mean what's the order ?

Comment: Its a third order system: [1 (parameter) 9 1]

I want to set the (parameter) coefficient in the mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you should be doing :

- take a Atomic Subsystem
- add Transfer Fcn block, with Denominator as *`[1 X 9 1]`*
- Mask this Atomic Subsystem, with parameter say *`X`* named say *`Coefficient`*.

Here's an example, (sorry mine is too old Student's version of matlab, but you'll get what to do.)

[image]

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for. Follow up, can you designate the atomic system to have multiple inputs and multi outputs?

Comment: @user3821411 All you've to do is add more Inports and Ouports, and perform logic inside it accordingly, if you've something specific, please post as new question

Answer (score 0):

Put your transfer function in a masked subsystem with one input and one output. Hard-code all the parameters of the transfer function block, except the one of interest, which you can then define as a mask parameter. You can't change the mask of the built-in transfer function block, so you have to create your own mask.

Comment: Not too sure how I would do this, if I put just the tf in a subsystem, the when I try to reference that one parameter, its still going to askfor the entire denominator, isn't it?

Comment: No, because you would hard code the other parameters in the TF block, and only leave the one parameter of interest as a mask parameter. The TF block will ask you for the whole denominator, but not your own mask  because you are constructing this yourself. The end-user of the model never sees the TF block dialog, only your own masked subsystem dialog box.  See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/mask-a-subsystem.html for an example of how to create a masked subsystem.

Comment: @P0W's answer illustrates what I was trying to say.